# Is it posssible to sign JavaApplicationStub with intstall4j?

Tags: java, macos, install4j

I'm trying to create a macOS Single bundle archive for my Java program. But you know MacOs have some new security rule. So i subscribe for an Developer ID Application for generate the archive.
When i launch  the build after uploading the archive it come back with this response from Apple :

```
{
  "logFormatVersion": 1,
  "jobId": "X",
  "status": "Invalid",
  "statusSummary": "Archive contains critical validation errors",
  "statusCode": 4000,
  "archiveFilename": "XXX.dmg",
  "uploadDate": "2021-02-11T15:54:19Z",
  "sha256": "",
  "ticketContents": null,
  "issues": [
    {
      "severity": "error",
      "code": null,
      "path": "XXX.dmg/XXX.app/Contents/MacOS/JavaApplicationStub",
      "message": "The signature of the binary is invalid.",
      "docUrl": null,
      "architecture": "x86_64"
    }
  ]
}
```

So i try everything but i don't know how to sign the JavaApplication with install4j.
I'm sorry if i done some error in my english writing.
I'm trying to learn ^ ^ .
Thank you

Comment: This could happen if you have exported the wring certificate instead of the "Developer ID Application" certificate.

Comment: I don't know but the other binary file are signed so i think install4j don't sign the JavaApllicationStub file (But Apple check it )

Comment: install4j does sign the stubs of generated launchers. Are you referring to those or some other 3rd party launcher? Please inspect the signatures with `codesign -vvv`

Comment: I done it. this is the result : XXX_macos_3_0.dmg: valid on disk

XXXX_macos_3_0.dmg: satisfies its Designated Requirement

Comment: And it's the stub of the generated launcher.

Comment: I mean check the JavaApplicationStub, not the DMG. Also what version of install4j do you use?

Comment: XXX.app/Contents/MacOs/JavaApplicationStub: a sealed resource is missing or invalid

file added: XXX.app/Contents/Resources/app/progs/programme_Kiné+ Niv1_digital.pdf

file added: XXX.app/Contents/Resources/app/progs/programme_Kiné+ Niv2_digital.pdf

file missing: XXX.app/Contents/Resources/app/progs/programme_Kiné+ Niv1_digital.pdf

file missing: XXX.app/Contents/Resources/app/progs/programme_Kiné+ Niv2_digital.pdf


Do you think those file names are the problem ?

And my install4j version is the last one.

Comment: Can you try renaming file so that is does not have any accents? Sometimes file name encoding issues can cause this problem.

Comment: So I rename those file and change my java code to work with it. And the notarizatzion worked. Thank you.